Creating a Chrome Extension to add a custom messgae in GMail Body When we Click on Compose Button
I am creating a custom Chrome Extension, which add custom Signature in Mail Body Whenever I Click on compose button
Manifest File (manifest.json)
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Cutom Email",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Insert Signature.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "xxx.png",
    "48": "uyy.png",
    "128": "zzz.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}

Back.js
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.includes('mail.google.com')) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      files: ['content.js']
    });
  }
});

Content Script (content.js)
function injectMessage() {
  const message = "Your static message here.";
  
  const composeButton = document.querySelector('div[gh="cm"]');
  if (composeButton) {
    composeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            const composeBody = document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Message Body"]');
            if (composeBody) {
              composeBody.focus();
              composeBody.innerHTML += `<br><br>${message}`;
              observer.disconnect();
            }
          }
        }
      });

      observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    });
  }
}


window.addEventListener('load', injectMessage);

However Nothing Happens. Let me know What I am doing wrong and how to rectify it

If you debug the content script in devtools by setting a breakpoint in injectMessage() you will probably see that composeButton is null. In that case you need to use MutationObserver instead of load event.

I tested it locally. and it works fine.
